# HttpClient stripping parameters from request

Tags: c#

I have code that calls a controller function on my site:

```
int id1 = 1;
int id2 = 2;
int id3 = 3;

var url = $"http://blah.com/blah?Id1={id1}&Id2={id2}&Id3={id3}";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
```

In the controller

```
public ActionResult blah(int Id1, int Id2, int Id3)
```

The issue i am having is that blah is never called because it is stripping off the parameters. If i turn the Functions parameters into nullables it hits the code.

I verified the url is parsing correctly by copying it from my watch into the browser. Hit blah as expected

Comment: is blah marked as POST or GET?

Comment: not decorated. so GET is the default, right?

Comment: What values are you passing for the parameters?

Comment: integers. the $ is shorthand for string.format its equivelent to string.Format ("Id1={0}&Id2={1}&Id3={2}", id1, id2, id3)

Comment: also i verified the url is correct by copying it from my watch into the browser. Hit blah as expected

Comment: could you please post the declaration and value setting of id1, id2 and id3

Comment: Do you have any special routing going on? What happens if you try to navigate to that url in a browser?

Comment: if i copy and paste the contents the url variable into the browser, i hit blah as expected.

Comment: Is any authentication required on that action? If you inspect the response, what is the ResponseCode and ReasonPhrase?

Comment: No authentication required and i'm thinking the response code is 500. The actual function call creates documents and the document contains the yellow screen error (The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id1' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method ...)

Comment: i verified the response code is 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated your issue using webapi 2 and default project settings.

My environment is windows 10 using iis.

I have a wpf application (for triggering dummy request like this one)

```
private async void DummyRequest()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
    int id1 = 1;
    int id2 = 2;
    int id3 = 3;
    HttpResponseMessage xResp = await client.GetAsync($"http://localhost:52089/api/test?id1={id1}&id2={id2}&id3={id3}");
}
```

and now the web api project code:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetTest(int id1, int id2, int id3)
{
    if (id1 != 1)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok("Values are correct");
}
```

This is working in all ways. I think the problem lays in the routing options

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a routing issue. Were you able to recreate the issue or was this code working in all ways?

Comment: ok, thanks. i was kinda hoping you meant you recreated the error and found a fix

Comment: We had code in rthe global file that was ending a session on session start (to enforce time outs) this was causing the httpclient to try and access the calls anonymously